# repetition time of adding data list

Tags: vb.net

resembles a python code like this

```
 while listCompanion :
```

in vb net I tried to use the code `For Each kvp In listCompanion` but failed

```
Dim listCompanion As New Dictionary(Of String, String()) From {"dessy", New String() {"age: 21", "gender: girl"}}
Dim kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String())
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
For Each kvp In listCompanion
  Dim member As String = String.Format("{0} = {1} - {2}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value(0), kvp.Value(1))
  ListBox1.Items.Add(member) 'I want every additions will enter the listbox
  If listCompanion.Count < 2 Then    'Error here
       listCompanion.Add({"jony", New String() {"age: 25", "gender: boy"}})
  End If
next
```

when you want to add a data list, the For Each actually not working again

I want after `listCompanion.Add({"jony", New String() {"age: 25", "gender: boy"}})`

can repeat  `For Each kvp In listCompanion`

Comment: It would be easier to use a concrete Type in a list especially if the 2 collections are supposed to be related somehow.  your question is unclear though (very)

Comment: If it's a `dictionary`, don't call it's reference `list`. You'll thank me 3 months from now when you try to understand your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems that don't allow your code to compile.

First you miss a couple of curly braces in the initialization of the listCompanion,

```
Dim listCompanion = New Dictionary(Of String, String()) From 
    { {"dessy", New String() {"age: 21", "gender: girl"}}}
```

Second there are too many curly braces when you add a new element to the listCompanion.

```
If listCompanion.Count < 2 Then    'Error here
    listCompanion.Add("jony", New String() {"age: 25", "gender: boy"})
End If
```

Finally you can't change the listCompanion while you loop over it, so if you want to add that KeyValuePair also to the Listbox items then you should add it before starting the loop

```
Dim kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String())
ListBox1.Items.Clear()

If listCompanion.Count < 2 Then    'Error here
    listCompanion.Add("jony", New String() {"age: 25", "gender: boy"})
End If

For Each kvp In listCompanion
    Dim member As String = String.Format("{0} = {1} - {2}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value(0), kvp.Value(1))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(member) 'I want every additions will enter the listbox
Next
```